# Fancybox 2 don't work on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am pretty new to jQuery and I have never been using fancybox before. I tried to install it, but it doesn't work. I used several test scripts I found, but still nothing. Here is my code:
In head I have following (Paths to all files are correct):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in my test document:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

    /* Using custom settings */

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });


});
</script>
<a id="single_image" title="" href=""><img src="http://localhost/images/something.png" alt="" /></a>
```

But when I click on the image, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring your jquery script last. That include should be first, preceeded by any other script that uses jquery. nothing to do if it's on localhost or not.

```
<script src="http://localhost/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/scripts/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't help.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the error you are getting. If using Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+J then Console. There must be an error that pops up to guide you into fixing the problem

Comment: Console is without error.. but I tried remove everything else from my page and It works. It looks like the problem is my second, own css file, but I don't know why.

Comment: Try to include your own CSS first, and then Fancybox/jQuery css and see if that helps? Could be your css has some styles defined that fancybox uses and you're overwriting it. Including yours first should help negate that issue

Comment: I tested it lot and I think, It works only when there are no blocks of code like <div id=""></div> on the page. But I have no idea why.

Comment: I did some magic, and managed to fancybox works with textbox, however gallery still don't work, but I am satisfied for now.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue when your jquery-2.1.1.js.  Once I used fancybox's provided jquery-1.10.1.js it worked however I got curious and tried jquery-1.9.1.js and my document stopped rendering the results.

I don't know if it helps or you figured it out already but I thought I would add what I found.